# G-invariant vector field

Tags: group-actions, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a compact manifold provided with an action of a Lie group $G$.

Let $X$ be a vector field on $M$. What does it mean to say that $X$  is $G$-invariant ?

Comment: If $G$ acts on $M$ then it also acts on the set of vector fields of $M$ doesn't it?

Comment: Lecture 2 in : https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~lerman/519/s12/427notes.pdf

Comment: in short it means: derivative mapping of Lie groups action on manifold(Vector field (x)) = Vector field (gx)  where g is an element in lie group.

Comment: @Balaji thanks for the reference. But it contains just the notion of left invariant vector field on a Lie group. Following this definition, am I right in thinking that the definition of an invariant vector field X on $M$ is ${ ( a_g)}_*X =X$, where $a_g : M \rightarrow M $ denotes the action of $g \in G$ on M ?

Comment: @Balaji thanks for your answer. Could you please just confirm to me whether the definition I wrote is right or no ?

Comment: what is the definition of $(a_g)_{*}$ in ur equation ?

Comment: I mean by ${(a_g)}_*(X)$ the pushforward of the vector field $X$ by the map $a_g$. In the case of lie groups in the reference  $a_g$ was  $ l_g$ (the left multiplication by $g$). 
To be more precise I'm following the definition in this post  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730603/pushforward-of-a-vector-field-by-a-diffeomorphism

Comment: I think u r correct..just to be clear:  derivative mapping of Lie groups action of the element g on manifold(Vector field (x)) = Vector field (action of g on x)... See https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.lnms/1215540660